# Just curious, any way around MustOverride in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to not be forced to include members with the MustOverride property when you inherit? I'm working on a custom MembershipProvider, and I only need access to a few members. It's purely an aesthetic thing - I just hate having to stub out 100 lines of unused member declarations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can right click the inherited class and select "Implement this ..." and it will create the method definitions for you throwing NotImplementedException() until you rewrite the method's code.

Comment: Spiffy! That saves some time. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

MustOverride (abstract in C#) specifies that it must be overridden.  There is no way around this.

You can have Visual Studio stub out the features for you, but they need to exist in order for the class to be instantiated.

One other option: If you'll be doing multiple versions, you can make a class that implements the members (throwing NotImplementedException, or doing nothing), and then derive from THAT class.  Your concrete version only would need to have the specific methods overriden that you wish.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not.
Btw, MustOverride is usually called abstract in C#.

Comment: Not usually called, IS called.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is... Declare your class as abstract, too! :-P

Now, seriously, just think about it. If you would not implement an abstract member in a non-abstract class, imagine what would happen at runtime, when calling a method without implementation? In C++, this was possible, and you would get a "Pure virtual function call" error.